# Is there something wrong with the way Stack Exchange is sorting sites by name?

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, sorting

There seems to be something wrong with the sorting of Stack Exchange sites by name:

[image: Stack Exchange sites listed by name with Elementary OS and Русский язык at the end of the list]

elementary OS and Русский язык appear in the wrong place at the end of the list.

Comment: `e` has the Unicode code point `101` which comes after `87` for `W`. `Р` has `1056` and `ス` has `12473`. So they’re sorted by Unicode code points, not alphabetically and case-insensitive.

Comment: I think this rank will mislead users.

Comment: Tagging this as a `bug` because sort-by-name should not be case sensitive. Changing the logic to `ORDER BY UPPER(Name)` *feels* like a 10-second fix; but I have no insight about how we handle Cyrillic-Latin equivalents.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Xufox notes in the comments, they're sorted case-sensitive and that Р is not a Latin P but a Cyrillic 'R', so it's outside the Latin alphabet. I think that page was created while all Stack Exchange sites started with a Latin capital letter.

It does make sense to sort elementary OS between Electrical Engineering and Emacs, but Русский язык will never fit in. Or, alternatively, change the name to "Elementary OS". There are probably many elementary OS enthusiasts who'd nail me to a cross for this, but [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) also starts with a capital letter even though [vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) does not.

Comment: In the site dropdown you see on every page in the top right, elementaryOS is listed with all the other E's. It's not like it's not trivial to sort things properly, so I think that changing the site name is overkill.